# Partially fill a Rectangle object

Tags: c#, drawrectangle

I was wondering if it's possible to fill a certain percentage of a Rectangle object that's been draw on-screen so that it behaves like a Progress Bar, where you can watch its "level" go up and down. Specifically, I'd like to fill it from top to bottom rather than left to right.

Comment: Perhaps you could put a smaller rectangle inside a larger one, and entirely fill the inner one.  Then make the inner one larger in stages.

Comment: That was what I was thinking for a backup after not being able to manipulate filling to work on only part of the Rectangle, I just thought I'd also look at what someone with more experience in this than myself might suggest. Glad to know it's not an asinine idea!

Comment: Note that DrawRectangle is off by one at the bottom right! Other than that using a growing 2nd rectangle, (or, simpler: the overload with four integers and a growing height and a shrinking y) is the way to go.. You may also want to study LinearGradientBrush for color effects!

Comment: This idea has worked well so far, the only problem I've encountered is that it "fills" the outer rectangle from the top to the bottom, rather than bottom to top. I'm working with some RotateTransforms and TranslateTransform, but it's being kind of a pain. The actual Progress Bar concept works though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Width = 400;
    panel1.Height = 50;

    using (Graphics g = this.panel1.CreateGraphics()) 
    {
        g.Clear(Color.Black);
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);               
        for (int i = 0; i <= 50;i++ )
        {
            g.DrawRectangle(pen, 0, 0, 400, i);                    
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }                   
        pen.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at this, it seems like this code would draw a Rectangle whose actual height scales, rather than just the color inside of its bounding edges?

Comment: @AlexWatts: Did you try it?